# VB.NET EF Core 7.0.15 Postgres column does not exist __$VB$Local__obj_id_0

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-core

I'm getting a strange error from the following code in .NET 7, EF Core 7.0.15:

```
Dim test = dbContext.invoiceItem.Where(Function(bb) bb.invoiceId = _obj.id)
```

> 42703: column "__$vb$local__obj_id_0" does not exist
>
> POSITION: 129

The generated query looks like so:

```
-- @__$VB$Local__obj_id_0='f26f3675-e0d6-4585-a64f-cb38e2f35c8e'
SELECT i.id, i.amt, i."customerId", i."desc", i."invoiceId", i."itemId", i.qty
FROM "invoiceItem" AS i
WHERE i."invoiceId" = @__$VB$Local__obj_id_0
```

The configuration for the database is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Invoice)(Sub(builder)
                                     builder.HasKey(Function(bb) bb.id)
                                     If customerTenant Then builder.HasQueryFilter(Function(bb) bb.customerId = currentCustomer)
                                     builder.Property(Function(bb) bb.id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                                     builder.HasIndex(Function(bb) bb.status)
                                     builder.HasIndex(Function(bb) bb.customerId)
                                     builder.HasIndex(Function(bb) bb.created)
                                     builder.HasIndex(Function(bb) bb.amt)
                                     builder.HasOne(Function(bb) bb.customer).WithMany(Function(bb) bb.invoices).HasForeignKey(Function(bb) bb.customerId)

                                     builder.Property(Function(bb) bb.created).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.UtcNow)
                                     builder.ToTable("invoice")
                                 End Sub)
```

There are no other settings that I am aware of. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? It looks like a matter of casing but I could be way off. A simple fix seems to be `$"{obj.id}"` but this is not a fun fix to put into the codebase.

EDIT:

I have since found a solution that seems to work. I'm not sure of the performance implications on larger solutions but for now this seems to work. I added an interceptor that analyzes for these bad actor names in the parameters, swapping each parameters name with something new and unique.

```
Public Class VBQueryInterceptor
    Inherits DbCommandInterceptor
    Private Const badPrefix As String = "@__$vb$local"
    Public Overrides Function ReaderExecuting(command As DbCommand, eventData As CommandEventData, result As InterceptionResult(Of DbDataReader)) As InterceptionResult(Of DbDataReader)
        If command.CommandText.ToLowerInvariant.Contains(badPrefix) Then
            For Each param As DbParameter In command.Parameters
                If param.ParameterName.ToLowerInvariant.StartsWith(badPrefix) Then
                    Dim varPrefix = "@" & GenerateUniqueShortID()
                    command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace(param.ParameterName, varPrefix)
                    param.ParameterName = varPrefix
                End If
            Next
        End If
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```